# Linq to XSD for Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, class-library, linq-to-xsd

It appears that the LINQ to XSD project has some dependencies on types that are not available in Silverlight, such as System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaType. Considering that, I know it would take a significant amount of work to get LINQ to XSD to work in a Silverlight project, but I am curious, has anyone modified the LINQ to XSD project (Microsoft.Xml.Schema.Linq) to compile as a Silverlight class library?

Or, I suppose another possibility would be if anyone has spent the time to develop the missing classes from the System.Xml.Schema namespace for Silverlight.

Thanks!

Comment: Just curious, why would you want linq to xsd in Silverlight? Seems that linq to xsd is more of a server-side technology, not something to be used in a client app.

Comment: This Silverlight app I'm working on has to manipulate an XML document. One could argue that maybe the client app isn't the place for this logic, but that's irrelevant. The bottom line is that I have a requirement to do it, so I'm stuck with it, and LINQ to XSD would be GREAT if I could use it.

Comment: if you're already working with LINQtoXSD on the server its a natural fit to use it on the client - especially for LOB applications.